# Does openmaptiles support distributing 3D terrain map tiles?

Tags: cesiumjs, openmaptiles

Can OpenMapTiles software dispense 3D terrain data?

I would like to render 3D terrain data in Cesium where the user can see the 3D terrain heights of the terrain when viewed from the side in an offline map server environment.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is this Cesium sandcastle example https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Terrain.html

I am familiar with OpenMapTiles' hillshade and contour map tiles.  My understanding is that hillshade tiles are raster only.

I would like to use USGS National Elevation Dataset (NED) tiles, but I don't know how to convert that data to a vector format that OpenMapTiles could send and Cesium could understand.

Looking at the Cesium documentation for imagery providers it looks like Cesium is looking for data in a "quantized-mesh" format for one image provider type.  I am not exactly sure what the GoogleEarthEnterprise or VRTheWorldTerrainProvider formats are using.

Any pointers or suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks